# Expect Script - spawn snmpwalk issue

Tags: bash, expect, snmp, spawn

I'm wondering why my two spawn commands return me a timeout error and an error while when I manually run them in the terminal they work.

```
[root@machine1 IDENTIFIER]# bash identifier.sh ip.list 
spawn snmpwalk -v 2c -Cc -c 'TEST' x.x.x.x .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 
Timeout: No Response from x.x.x.x
x.x.x.x | TIMEOUT 

spawn snmpwalk -v 2c -Cc -c 'TEST' x.x.x.x .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 
Error in packet. 
Reason: noAccess 
Failed object: SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0
x.x.x.x | ERROR 

Process finished!
```

Here are my simplified sources:

**IDENTIFIER.SH**

```
#!/bin/bash

log="LOGG/identifier-"`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`".csv"
row=$(cat $1 | wc -l)
declare -A tab
compt=0

for rows in $(cat $1);do
   tab[$compt]=$rows
   compt=`expr $compt + 1`
done

compt=0

for k in `seq 0 $(($rows-1))`;do
   ./identifier.expect ${tab[$compt]} $log &
   compt=`expr $compt + 1`
   wait
done

echo "Process finished!"
```

**IDENTIFIER.EXPECT**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set ip [lindex $argv 0];
set log [lindex $argv 1];
set _timeout 0

log_file $log
log_user 1

spawn snmpwalk -v 2c -Cc -c \'TEST\' $ip .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0

expect {
  "Timeout"        { puts "$ip | TIMEOUT"
                     send_log "$ip,TIMEOUT\n"                   }
  "Cisco"          { puts "$ip | CISCO"
                     send_log "$ip,CISCO\n"                     }
  "Digi"           { puts "$ip | DIGI"
                     send_log "$ip,DIGI\n"                      }
  "Error"          { puts "$ip | ERROR"
                     send_log "$ip,ERROR\n"                     }
       }
```

Thx !

Comment: did you write `set _timeout` or `set timeout` in your expect script ? You might want to use a value greater than 0 for the timeout, otherwise the script will exit after 0 seconds

Comment: I wrote `set _timeout 0`, so the script doesnt exit after this value.